# Почему невозможно поменять поменять позицию actor в libgdx после добавления в Stage?

Tags: java, libgdx

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    btch.begin();
    btch.end();
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
    player.setPosition(0, 0); //не работает!
}
```

player это Image, вернее EntityObject
Часть метода:

```
@Override
public void create() {
    EntityObject player = new EntityObject(new 
        Texture(Gdx.files.internal("resources/images/player.jpeg")));
    stage.addActor(player);
}
```

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос, т.к. непонятно, что за переменная `player`

Comment: Если переменная player описана в методе create, откуда к нему доступ имеет render ?

Comment: Обьявлено вне create!

Comment: public void create() {
    EntityObject player = new EntityObject
может и объявлено, но новый объект вы записываете не туда